# Azure webdeployment I/O Error create directory wwwroot

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy

Since this morning our Azure website went down (HTTP 500 The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.)

I cannot redeploy my Azure website due to an I/O error and I cannot even access the websites log files. There was nothing on the visual studio project or Azure website configuration.

Anyone who encountered the same problem and has a solution for that?

Webdeploy output:

```
2>Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to https://xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd?site=xxx ...
2>sitemanifest (sitemanifest) wird hinzugefügt.
2>Der virtuelle Pfad (xxx) wird hinzugefügt.
2>Das Verzeichnis (xxx) wird hinzugefügt.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4269,5): Error : Web deployment task failed. ((19.11.2014 11:22:15) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)
2>

2>(19.11.2014 11:22:15) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
2>Fehler bei der Verarbeitung des Vorgangs "Verzeichnis erstellen" für "wwwroot".
2>
2>I/O error occurred.
2>Publish failed to deploy.
2>
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

azure web storage is down in western and northern europe

In relation to the question.   I/O   is related to disk input and output.   The disk is used to store files, that are then served by IIS on azure websites.

Azure call this disk,  Storage,   or Azure storage.

At the time in question, Azure Storage was down,   this meant that operations to write onto a disk / storage was disabled,  resulting in the following error reported by the OP.

Microsoft have now finished most of these issues, So another attempt should now yield the correct result.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: this was the answer @GNi33   the azure storage block for websites, in north Europe and west Europe was down this morning,   what other response do you recommend, when this IS the answer, if the op tries now, he will find that everything now works fine.   So   if you know of a better answer, then please, do enlighten us

Comment: added link http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/#history   to confirm answer is the most probably answer in this circumstance